# IIS - HTTPS and WWW Redirect

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

So i'm using iis 8 and trying to redirect all versions of my site to 1.

Say for example:

```
http://www.osrshub.com
www.osrshub.com
osrshub.com
http://osrshub.com
https://osrshub.com
https://www.osrshub.com
```

When a user hits any of these links i need it to redirect to 1 main link.

```
https://www.osrshub.com
```

Im using windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

This rule will redirect everything to `https://www.osrshub.com`:

```
<rule name="All in one rule" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.osrshub\.com$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.osrshub.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

You need to add this rule in your web.config file